# How to apply CSS to a child component html that is used in the angular project via 3rd party NPM module?

Tags: css, angular, html

I have included a 3rd party pagination module for my angular application. It is working perfectly except that it does have some html that I don't want on my view.
I tried to hide that mark-up by applying `display: none !important;` CSS property but it did not work so I had to pass

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

to my component decorator and it started working. Only problem I have with this approach is when I route away from the current component. It messes up with the button styles of my dashboard component. This problem also goes away on dashboard if either I reload the page or navigate to another route.

Is there any decent solution to this?

Comment: Couldn't you just hide it from your gloabl styles.css or theme.css?

Comment: You might want to check on the documentation of the pagination module. There might be a chance that you can provide your own component html.

Comment: I had to override the styles for buttons in my dashboard component and it started working. before this, they were added  in styles.css file.